# Kendo UI chart control -- changing format of y-axis labels

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz, kendo-chart

I am using Chart control in Kendo. I want to change the color and format of the negative values in my valueAxis. If it's a negative value, I want to: change the font color to RED and show the format as e.g. "(-1234)"

Below is my snippet but its not working

```
valueAxis: [{
    name: "value",
    labels: {
        //format: '{0:###,###,###,###}'
        template: "#= (Value < 0 ? '<span style=\\'color:red\\'>(':'') + kendo.toString(Math.abs(value),'\\#\\#\\#,\\#\\#\\#.00') + (value < 0 ? ')</span>':'')"
    }
}],
```

How can I achieve that? thank you for your help.

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle for the same?

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure how to create the chart in jsfiddle, but this already existing chart can be used: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/ZPUr4/144/

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use HTML spans within an SVG rendered chart.  Instead use the **[visual property](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart#configuration-valueAxis.labels.visual)** of the valueAxis to render **[SVG text](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/drawing/text)**:

```
valueAxis: {
    labels: {
        visual: function(e) {
          var center = e.rect.center();
          var fillCol = e.value < 0 ? "red" : e.options.color;
          var text = e.value < 0 ? "(" + e.text + ")" : e.text;
          return new kendo.drawing.Text(text, e.rect.origin, {
            fill: {
              color: fillCol
            }
          })
        }
    },
},
```

## **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/AxImo)**

Comment: Thanks. i am getting this error on kendo.drawing.Text  --> Supplied parameters do not match any signature of the call target.

Comment: @user6048082, Did you run the demo: http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/AxImo? You can add console.log(e) to the visual function and inspect it.